# Windows Registry Location Error Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, registry, inno-setup, chromium

im trying to figure out how to install a extension as a installer via Windows Registry. Google only allows extensions to be installed from the web store, or Windows Registry. I've been bangin my head with this for the last few days. Ok I have the correct key/values for the Registry. But for some reason when I run the Inno installer, the extension does not get installed.

1)Google Dev Tutorial says: The data type is a string and the windows registry location is as such:
Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallForcelist

2) Google Dev Tutorial also gives an example such as:
Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallForcelist\1 = "lcncmkcnkcdbbanbjakcencbaoegdjlp;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

Below is a snippet of my registry. (Below is a link that gives instructions for force installations, which is what I'm, trying to do
http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist)

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallForcelist";
                 ValueType: string; ValueName: "FavMovie"; ValueData: "igcijckafdbfnikpopgapfedkceligpn;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "                     {cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";       Flags: ignoreversion
                ; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Chrome Extension"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Chrome Extension"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Chrome Extension}";   Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: Shouldn't you store the value e.g. under `Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallForcelist\1` key (where the 1 is the list index; if that is so, you should also write some logic to append to such list) ? Also, are you sure about the value name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document you quote](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3):

> Note: Starting with Chromium 28, policies are loaded directly from the Group Policy API on Windows. Policies manually written to the registry will be ignored.

See also the respective [Chromium Blog announcement](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html).

You can still trigger an install [through the registry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry) **if the extension is published on CWS**, or **if your computer is part of a domain** and you control the group policy on that domain.